# How to find content in a file and replace the adjecent value

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Using bash how do I find a string and update the string next to it for example pass value

```
my.site.com|test2.spin:80
```

**proxy_pass.map**

```
my.site2.com           test2.spin:80
my.site.com            test.spin:8080;
```

Expected output is to update **proxy_pass.map** with

```
my.site2.com           test2.spin:80
my.site.com            test2.spin:80;
```

I tried using awk

```
awk '{gsub(/^my\.site\.com\s+[A-Za-z0-9]+\.spin:8080;$/,"my.site2.comtest2.spin:80"); print}' proxy_pass.map
```

but does not seem to work. Is there a better way to approch the problem. ?

Comment: do you need to maintain the spacing between the columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `awk` idea, assuming spacing needs to be maintained:

```
awk -v rep='my.site.com|test2.spin:80' '

BEGIN      { split(rep,a,"|")                                   # split "rep" variable and store in 
             site[a[1]]=a[2]                                    # associative array
           }

$1 in site { line=$0                                            # if 1st field is in site[] array then make copy of current line

             match(line,$1)                                     # find where 1st field starts (in case 1st field does not start in column #1)
             newline=substr(line,1,RSTART+RLENGTH-1)            # save current line up through matching 1st field
             line=substr(line,RSTART+RLENGTH)                   # strip off 1st field

             match(line,/[^[:space:];]+/)                       # look for string that does not contain spaces or ";" and perform replacement, making sure to save everything after the match (";" in this case)
             newline=newline substr(line,1,RSTART-1) site[$1] substr(line,RSTART+RLENGTH)

             $0=newline                                         # replace current line with newline
           }
1                                                               # print current line
' proxy_pass.map
```

This generates:

```
my.site2.com           test2.spin:80
my.site.com            test2.spin:80;
```

If the input looks like:

```
$ cat proxy_pass.map
my.site2.com           test2.spin:80
  my.site.com          test.spin:8080;
```

This `awk` script generates:

```
my.site2.com           test2.spin:80
  my.site.com          test2.spin:80;
```

**NOTES:**

- if multiple replacements need to be performed I'd suggest placing them in a file and having `awk` process said file first
- the 2nd `match()` is hardcoded based on OP's example; depending on actual file contents it may be necessary to expand on the regex used in the 2nd `match()`
- once satisified with the result the original input file can be updated in a couple ways ... a) if using `GNU awk` then `awk -i inplace -v rep....` or b) save result to a temp file and then `mv` the temp file to `proxy_pass.map`

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following `awk` code. Creating shell variable named `var` where it stores value `my.site.com|test2.spin:80` in it. which further is being passed to `awk` program. In `awk` program creating variable named `var1` which has shell variable var's value in it.

In `BEGIN` section of `awk` using `split` function to split value of `var`(shell variable's value container) into array named arr with separator as `|`. Where `num` is total number of values delimited by split function. Then using `for` loop to be running till value of `num` where it creates array named `arr2` with index of current `i` value and making i+1 as its value(basically 1 is for key of array and next item is value of array).

In main block of `awk` program checking condition if `$1` is in arr2 then print arr2's value else print $2 value as per requirement.

```bash
##Shell variable named var is being created here...
var="my.site.com|test2.spin:80"

awk -v var1="$var" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(var1,arr,"|")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i+=2){
    arr2[arr[i]]=arr[i+1]
  }
}
{
  print $1,(($1 in arr2)?arr2[$1]:$2)
}
' Input_file
```

---

---

***OR*** in case **you want to maintain spaces** **between 1st and 2nd field(s)** then try following code little tweak of Above code. Written and tested with your shown samples Only.

```bash
awk -v var1="$var" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(var1,arr,"|")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i+=2){
    arr2[arr[i]]=arr[i+1]
  }
}
{
  match($0,/[[:space:]]+/)
  print $1 substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) (($1 in arr2)?arr2[$1]:$2)
}
'   Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** This program can take multiple values separated by `|` in shell variable to be passed and checked on in `awk` program. But it considers that it will be in format of `key|value|key|value...` only.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of spaces between the columns is not significant, a simple

```
proxyf=proxy_pass.map
tmpf=$$.txt
awk '$1 == "my.site.com" { $2 = "test2.spin:80;" } {print}' <$proxyf >$tmpf && mv $tmpf $proxyf
```

should do. If you need the columns to be lined up nicely, you can replace the `print` by a suitable `printf ....` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh -x

f1=$(echo "my.site.com|test2.spin:80" | cut -d'|' -f1)
f2=$(echo "my.site.com|test2.spin:80" | cut -d'|' -f2)

echo "${f1}%${f2};" >> proxy_pass.map
tr '%' '\t' < proxy_pass.map >> p1
cat > ed1 <<EOF
$
-1
d
wq
EOF
ed -s p1 < ed1
mv -v p1 proxy_pass.map
rm -v ed1
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
<<<'my.site.com|test2.spin:80' sed -E 's#\.#\\.#g;s#^(\S+)\|(\S+)#/^\1\\b/s/\\S+/\2/2#' |
sed -Ef - file
```

Build a sed script from the input arguments and apply it to the input file.

The input arguments are first prepared so that their metacharacters ( in this case the `.`'s are escaped.

Then the first argument is used to prepare a match command and the second is used as the value to be replaced in a substitution command.

The result is piped into a second sed invocation that takes the sed script and applies it the input file.